# Paging for Site Manager

Tags: sxa, multisite

I have few sites but I can't see all of them on the same page in Site Manager. There are presented in 2 pages but I don't see any option to go to page 2 which make hard to manage sites. Is there any configuration for making pagination visible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have pagination in the ribbon:

[image]